# Doctrine alter table causes auto_increment resequencing

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I'm trying to execute the update schema command on doctrine, but the operation is not completed because the follow error:

Command executed:

```
php doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

But the table on question at present don't have auto_increment. So, Doctrine are inserting auto_increment on my table without my will?

How I can pass for this error without insert auto_increment in my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem!

I removed the `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` annotation property of the respective attribute of the entity.

See the examples below:

Before:

```
   /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_usuario", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idUsuario;
```

After:

```
   /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_usuario", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $idUsuario;
```